# Android - Fatal Signal on simple MapFragment app

Tags: android, google-maps, mapfragment

I am creating a small exercise application and in it I am using the Google Maps API V2. I have got everything setup correctly from switching the API on to getting a debug API key.

The code is the most basic code too:

XML

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
   }
}
```

I load the above Activity from another using a simple intent:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, LocationActivity.class);
this.startActivity(i);
```

Everything works fine, the Activity loads fine and the map shows and can be panned and zoom in and out on it but when I press the back key I get the following error:

```
08-28 16:07:05.900    1959-2018/com.exercise.movieexercise A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000006 (code=1), thread 2018 (Thread-145)
```

And the application force closes. I am developing in Android Studio and testing on an emulator using 4.4.2 Google API's. Google hasn't been too helpful on the issue so I am wondering if anyone has any insight as to why this might be occurring?

Comment: Are you using Google's Emulator or Genymotion? Also if Google's Emulator, are you using the arm or x86 image?

Comment: Using Googles Emulator, tried on both arm and x86 and the behaviour is the same on both. I was hoping it was just a bug in my emulator but the fact that I can reproduce it across many emulators suggests it might not be.

Comment: The fact that it's happening in native code (`libc`) makes me think it still might have to with the fact that it's an emulator.

Comment: Possible, works on a real device and also on Genymotion emulators, I'll put it down to a bug in my emulators, thanks